# How to emulate subdomain/language in .htacces file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been looking at some way to implement the language subdomain behavior of the enterprise version of GTranslate and have come close.

Basically, if you want subdomains like fr.domain.com, es.domain.com, de.domain.com, etc
for the PRO version (general implementation), then there should be a way to handle this with modifications in the .htaccess file.

This isn't quite right, but it's coming close - for example, if you wanted "de.domain.com" for German, there might be a modification like:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\ /gtranslate/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://de.domain.com/gtranslate/translate.php?lang=de&url=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

The Condition is to prevent recursion... This seems to come close, but the problem is that the URL in the browser now shows `de.domain.com/gtranslate/translate.php?lang=de&url=about.html` instead of the desired `de.domain.com/about.html`

There must be a way to handle this so that we can emulate this behavior.

Motivation: Perhaps I should have stated this up top.

1. I'm using the general version with Joomla - seems to work most of the time, BUT it looses the language during a form submission because the redirection (POST?) of the form looses the language code (normally a 2-letter prefix to the URL.
2. If I was able to keep a language per subdomain, then it seems like I would be able to properly keep the language during a form submission (as well as the potential "niceness" of having a subdomain to reflect the language - could even be the name of the country).

Anyone who is better in mod_rewrite want to take a stab at this?

Answer (score 0):

> There must be a way to handle this so that we can emulate this
>   behavior.

No. As soon as you do a `301` this is a full redirect, so the URL is modified, and, unfortunaltely, you can't avoid this.

Comment: So... perhaps not a 301. any other ways to do this?